# Editing a Wordpress widget

Tags: php, wordpress

I am using a Wordpress theme in which this is a code of widget ,

```
/* Widget settings. */
$widget_ops = array( 'classname' => 'maxmag_catlist_widget', 'description' => __('A widget that displays a list of posts from a category of your choice.', 'maxmag_catlist_widget') );

/* Widget control settings. */
$control_ops = array( 'width' => 150, 'height' => 200, 'id_base' => 'maxmag_catlist_widget' );

/* Create the widget. */
$this->WP_Widget( 'maxmag_catlist_widget', __('Max Mag: Category List Widget', 'maxmag_catlist_widget'), $widget_ops, $control_ops );
```

Here I want to edit the width of this widget , so I tried to change the line

```
$control_ops = array( 'width' => 150, 'height' => 200, 'id_base' => 'maxmag_catlist_widget' );
```

However it changed nothing. I don't know a bit of php, but I have some coding knowledge, can anyone please help me with this?

Comment: $control_ops is the settings for the backend, where you set settings for the widget. If you want to change the width of the widget on the site, you would need to change it's css most likely.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I took a look to the maxmag theme from themeforest ( i think you used this one) and i noted that in the style.css files it has this instruction (and others like this for other widget types):

```
.sidebar-widget {
    float: left;
    font: 400 12px/normal 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
    margin-bottom: 30px;
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 100%;
    }
```

I don't know which is the widget you have to change but I think that you can change the `width: 100%;` instruction to solve your problem.

L.

Comment: I want to change the widget which is here in middle named "Latest News" , take a look here .

http://themeforest.net/item/max-mag-responsive-wordpress-magazine-theme/full_screen_preview/3103810

The above solution dint worked out . :(

Comment: Try to edit the `.middle-widget` class in your style.css file.

`.middle-widget {
 float: left;
 font: 400 12px/normal 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
 margin-bottom: 20px;
 width: 100%; // edit this line
 }`